# Botbuilder SDK v4 creating 1:1 conversation from group

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm attempting to send a 1:1 / private message to a specific user who tagged the bot in channel in Microsoft Teams. Because there isn't a `botbuilder-teams` that is compatible with botbuilder v4, I figured I'd have to implement this functionality myself. I know with proactive messages, you can use `adapter.continueConversation` which works correctly, but `adapter.createConversation` does not. Here is the relevant piece of code within one of my dialogs:

```
let reference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(cx.activity);

await adapter.createConversation(reference, async (context) => {
    await context.sendActivity("Hello World!");
});
```

Comment: What's your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter for CreateConversation Method should be the channel ID, which is in your case "teams". You don't have to supply the existing conversation reference as you are creating a new one.